# Problem with strftime() offsetting dates one day?

Tags: r, strftime

Just developing a bit of code to import daily precip data from an Excel spreadsheet with read_xlsx and aggregate and sum by years and months. Created year and month columns and then used strftime() fill them with character years and months taken from a day date column. Discovered it put 1989 and 12 in the year and month columns for a 1990-01-01 day date. And all the way down all the filled in years & months are set back one day.

```
str(daily_dat)
data.frame':    11688 obs. of  3 variables:
$ day_date: POSIXct, format: "1990-01-01" "1990-01-02" ...
$ prcp_mm : num  0 14.99 4.06 0 0 ...

day_date    prcp_mm
1990-01-01  0
1990-01-02  14.986
1990-01-03  4.064
1990-01-04  0
1990-01-05  0
1990-01-06  0
1990-01-07  0
1990-01-08  1.016
1990-01-09  0
1990-01-10  0
1990-01-11  0
1990-01-12  0
1990-01-13  0
1990-01-14  0
1990-01-15  0
1990-01-16  0
1990-01-17  0
1990-01-18  0
1990-01-19  6.858
1990-01-20  0
1990-01-21  0
1990-01-22  3.048
1990-01-23  2.032
1990-01-24  0
1990-01-25  0
1990-01-26  0
1990-01-27  0
1990-01-28  0
1990-01-29  0
1990-01-30  0
1990-01-31  0
1990-02-01  0
1990-02-02  0`

daily_1$year<-strftime(daily_1$day_date,"%Y")
daily_1$month<-strftime(daily_1$day_date,"%m")
head(daily_1,33)

day_date    prcp_mm year    month
1990-01-01  0   1989    12
1990-01-02  14.986  1990    1
1990-01-03  4.064   1990    1
1990-01-04  0   1990    1
1990-01-05  0   1990    1
1990-01-06  0   1990    1
1990-01-07  0   1990    1
1990-01-08  1.016   1990    1
1990-01-09  0   1990    1
1990-01-10  0   1990    1
1990-01-11  0   1990    1
1990-01-12  0   1990    1
1990-01-13  0   1990    1
1990-01-14  0   1990    1
1990-01-15  0   1990    1
1990-01-16  0   1990    1
1990-01-17  0   1990    1
1990-01-18  0   1990    1
1990-01-19  6.858   1990    1
1990-01-20  0   1990    1
1990-01-21  0   1990    1
1990-01-22  3.048   1990    1
1990-01-23  2.032   1990    1
1990-01-24  0   1990    1
1990-01-25  0   1990    1
1990-01-26  0   1990    1
1990-01-27  0   1990    1
1990-01-28  0   1990    1
1990-01-29  0   1990    1
1990-01-30  0   1990    1
1990-01-31  0   1990    1
1990-02-01  0   1990    1
1990-02-02  0   1990    2

str(daily_1)
'data.frame':   11688 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ day_date: POSIXct, format: "1990-01-01" "1990-01-02" ...
 $ prcp_mm : num  0 14.99 4.06 0 0 ...
 $ year    : chr  "1989" "1990" "1990" "1990" ...
 $ month   : chr  "12" "01" "01" "01" ...
```

What the heck?

Comment: I am guessing that an incorrect timezone is being used. Try explicitly setting the `tz` parameter to `strftime`

Comment: Something like this?  'daily_1$month<-strftime(daily_1$day_date,"%m",tz = "MST")

Comment: Ran "Sys.setenv(TZ='America/Phoenix')" in the script and no change in output.

Comment: I saved the day_date column data with a timezone parameter "as.POSIXct(daily_dat$day_date,format="%Y-%m-%d",tz = "America/Phoenix")" and then ran the strftime function and no change. All dates still moved back one day.

Comment: I've tried three different fixes with no success. If I can't fix it that means Excel wins. Just sayin'.

Comment: instead of `strftime` perhaps just try `daily_1$month <- format(daily_1$day_date, '%m')`

Comment: Thanks br00t! Worked perfectly. Excel loses again!

Comment: Good stuff @Frank Reichenbacher!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `strftime` perhaps just try `daily_1$month <- format(daily_1$day_date, '%m')`